# Updated records don't match Store.sync()

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am having trouble when updating my store

```
Ext.define("ManageShows.model.Show", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id' , type: 'int'},
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ],
    validations: [
        { type: 'presence', field: 'name', message: 'Please enter a name for this show.'}
    ]
}
});
```

When i try to sync() i get this error

```
[WARN][Ext.data.Operation#process] Unable to match the updated record that came back from the server.
```

The List holding the data then contains duplicate entries of the first element in the list. But if i refresh the page my list displays correctly with the updated term.

I don't know what part of the records that don't match. The only different i can see is that Store.id = "ext-record-4" which seem to be auto generated and i am not saving this value in my database but Store.data.id = {id from database}.

How can i find what is not matching?

EDIT: 
Important note is that i get the error 7 times in a row and i have 8 entries. If i updated the first entry then the changes work and is displayed corrently

Answer (score 0):

I stopped my servlet from returning json data after a sync() call.  This wasn't need because sencha touch updates the data locally automatically